# como aplico los archivos estaticos para todas las rutas y futuras que se vayan creando en express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose, ejs

necesito su ayuda ya he intentado configurar los archivos estaticos para cada una de las rutas que  vaya creando vaya aplicando los archivos css y js a cada vista. actualmente me funciona pero de esta manera

```
app.use('/articulos/editararticulos/:id', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/actdiarias/tactividades', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/editar/:id', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use('/desktops', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

como veran la de la segunda linea deberia servir para todas pero no me sirve :L de echo hasta e usado la expresion regular con asterisco * y tampoco :L entonces cada vista que voy creando no me carga los archivos estaticos y tenngo que estarlo configurando para cada ruta de cada vista :L gracias de antemano y disculpen la ignorancia XD